Cannot access/find file supplied with build
Im build a QT mobile app, and for test of search function I want to supply txt file. And as Title follows - I cant access it. here is cmakelists.txt file:
...
qt_add_executable(appTest
    src/main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appTest
    URI Test
    VERSION 1.0
    SOURCES
        src/main.cpp
        src/SocketCall.h src/SocketCall.cpp
        src/Searcher.h src/Searcher.cpp

    QML_FILES
        qml/LoginPage.qml
        ...

    RESOURCES
    android/Teachers.txt
    android/Cache.txt
)


set_target_properties(appTest PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(appTest
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS appTest
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

set_property(TARGET appTest PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")


And here is a block, that suppose to call it
    //QString CacheFilePath = QDir(":/android").filePath("Cache.txt");
    //QString DataFilePath = QDir(":/android").filePath("Teachers.txt"); <- tried those as well
    CacheFile.open("android/Cache.txt", std::ios::out);
    TeachersList.open("android/Teachers.txt", std::ios::in);
    qDebug() << TeachersList.is_open();
    qDebug() << CacheFile.is_open();
    //rest is not related

First 2 lines of code in cpp block is taken from tutorial and such, people suggested that one should access "assets" folder for files supplied with build, I tried changing paths multiple times(":/","assets:/", "android/assets" etc), also tried changing last Cmake line to
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/folder/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/tried-many-things-here)


, but couldt find file. Tried deleting them from resources, or only leaving them as resources. After that I tried to search inner memory of phone for it.
void Searcher::_Directory(QString _Input)
{
    QStringList List{QDir(_Input).entryList()};

    for (const auto& Iterator : List)
    {
        qDebug() << Iterator;
    }
        qDebug() << "/////////////////////////////////////////////";
}

using this function and TextField I traversed directories and printed results, here they are

First dot and 2 dots correlate to root folder, when i didnt put anything in path. All other entries is in "../". And I searched every one of them, there is nothing, or some system files. I tried to set destination path in cmake to some of those folder - still nothing. Right now Im kinda out of options what to try, to access those files.
All advices are welcome.
If something is not clear - I will try to provide more context.
